# How can you convert this boolean expression into CNF?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, boolean-algebra

I'm currently completely lost trying to show that these boolean expressions are equal: $$\bar abc\lor a\bar bc\lor ab\bar c = (a\lor c)(b\lor c)(a\lor b)(\bar a \lor \bar b\lor\bar c)$$
I spend almost 8 hours trying everything but never got far. This is the furthest I've got:
$$(\bar abc\lor a\bar bc)\lor ab\bar c \\= ([\bar abc \lor a][\bar abc \lor \bar b][\bar abc \lor c])\lor ab\bar c\\=
([1(a\lor b)(a\lor c)]\land[(\bar b\lor \bar a)1(\bar b\lor c)][(c\lor \bar a)(c\lor b)(c\lor c)])\lor ab\bar c\\=
c(a\lor b)(\bar b\lor \bar a)\lor ab\bar c$$

Is this proof really that complex or am I just missing something very easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You can in 1 step do something akin to FOIL on the second expression, i.e. combine one term from the first conjunct with one from the second, one from the third, and one from the fourth. Do this for all possible combinatins: This should get you $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 =24$ new terms:

$abaa'+abab'+abac'+abba'+abbb'+abbc'+....$

Now you can remove any term where you have a variable and its complement, since that term represents a contradiction/impossibility:

$abac'+abbc'+...$

Now you can remove duplicates of variables:

$abc'+abc'+...$

... and duplicates of terms:

$abc'+...$

You can also start with the left side and do an analgous process, but then the first step gets you $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 =27$ terms ... and given your high school number algebra experience it's probably not as intuitive to work with products of sums as opposed to sums of products, which is why I recommend going from right to left.

Finally, I should point out that you yourself are almost there anyway:

$c(a+b)(b'+a')+abc'=$ (FOIL)

$c(ab'+aa'+bb'+ba')+abc'=$(remove contradictions)

$c(ab'+ba')+abc'=$

$cab'+cba'+abc'=$(bunch of commutations)

$a'bc+ab'c+abc'$

Comment: Thank you, that makes way more sense

Comment: @SamuelBraun You are welcome! And yes, this is a very systematic method that will make it less likely to make mistakes or get stuck. Though with your original work you got very close yourself: I just added that to my Answer. And finally: you must have noticed I changed the notation ... this kind of notation is very efficient and maps nicely to your high school algebra experience, so I highly recommend it for practical purposes. Of course, your instructor may insist on using a certain notation so then you'll have to use that :P

Comment: yeah, your notation is way more intuitive, I had problems confusing "and" with "or" on a lot of the steps and not knowing what to do. I don't see the problem with this notation. And you can brainstorm faster.

Comment: @Kori Exactly! :)